# How to add a line (abline e.g.) into a plot in a loop function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, plot, lines

I have a dataset in which I need to plot each variable. I made a loop for this since the dataset contains like 50 variables. This is what I got thus far:

```
invisible(lapply(colnames(Data),function(x){
plot(Data[,x],main=x,type="l", xlab= 'Week number', ylab='Amount')
}))
```

This automatically plots all the variables in my dataset in separate plots. However, I need to plot lines in all of these plots. The idea is that I add an average line for each x. So a horizontal line on the height whichs corresponds to the value of the mean x. I tried to do this by adding the abline(h=mean(x)) function to the function above but this doesn't work. Do you guys have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: For `plot` functions, I tend to use `for` loops rather than `lapply`. I haven't had any problem like the one you mention here with `for(...){; plot(...); abline(...); };`.

Comment: Don't you mean you added `abline(h=mean(Data[,x]))`? It could also be due to `NA`s in the column; use `mean(Data[,x], na.rm=TRUE)`.

Comment: @MrGumble  thanks! This did the trick. I think it was due to the NA's that it was not working. Do you also know how I can add 2 lines, one 20% above average and one 20% below the average of x for only the last 5 values of x that are in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
abline(h=mean(Data[,x]))
```

not

```
abline(h=mean(x))
```

since each time x is a colnames. to check use this code

```
Data<-matrix(sqrt(1:20),ncol=4)
colnames(Data)<-c(letters[1:4])
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

invisible(lapply(colnames(Data),function(x){
plot(Data[,x],main=x,type="l", xlab= 'Week number', ylab='Amount')
abline(h=mean(Data[,x]))
}))
```